# button not blings while clicking if background image is added

Tags: android, button

Here is the button:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sam_back" />
```

When `selector` attribute is used it cannot be implemented because as `android:background` is already used for background image. Please help to solve this.

Comment: @drawable/sam_back is a image or selector??

Comment: see my answer it will solve your prob.:)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/gray"/> <!-- pressed -->
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/gray"/> <!-- focused -->
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/edittext_backround"/> <!-- default -->
    </selector>

1.make one xml with name buttonselector.xml
2.then set backround like this ..  android:background="@drawable/buttonselector" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/hover_btn" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn"/>

</selector>
```